# Symfony entity dynamic property from filter association properties

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, relationship, matching

It's possible to have an entity that looks like this code, and when I would like to instantiate this entity, the `dossierClientActif` properties are automatically a filter of `dossiersClient` properties.

```
class Contact {

    private id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $dossiersClient;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\DossierClient
     */
    private $dossierClientActif;

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getDossiersClient()
    {
        return $this->dossiersClient;
    }

    /**
     * Add dossierClient
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\DossierClient $dossierClient
     *
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function addDossierClient(\AppBundle\Entity\DossierClient $dossierClient)
    {
        $this->dossiersClient[] = $dossierClient;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DossierClient
     */
    public function getDossierClientActif()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
       $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('indArchive', 0));
       return $this->dossiersClient->matching($criteria)->first();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JMS serializer with virtual properties works for me.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Contact:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    virtual_properties:
        getDossierClientActif:
            serialized_name: dossierClientActif
            groups: ['contact']
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
            groups: ['contact']
        dossiersClient:
            expose: true
            groups: ['contact']
```